# Rails 5: Why can't I save nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with understanding this.

I have two models `Person` and `Address`. `Person` accepts nested attributes for `Address`.

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

I have a form `app/views/person/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  #...
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :apartment_number %>
    <%= ff.text_field :building_name %>
    <%= ff.text_field :building_number %>
    <%= ff.text_field :street %>
    <%= ff.text_field :town %>
    <%= ff.text_field :postcode, required: true %>
  <% end %>
#...
```

I have set up my strong params and I create the new record as follows:

```rb
  def create
    @person = Person.new(safe_params)

    if @person.save
      binding.pry
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def safe_params
    params.require(:person).permit(
      :name,
      :date_of_birth,
      address: %i[
        apartment_number
        building_name
        building_number
        street
        town
        postcode
      ]
    )
  end
```

However, there's two things going on here. If `@person` fails validation, the re-rendered `new` view does not contain the submitted address data. Secondly, if the save is successful I can see that the associated address is not created:

```
@person.address
=> nil
```

What do I need to do to ensure that an `address` is created and saved? Have I misunderstood something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs on nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) the strong parameters have to end with `_attributes`

```
params.require(:person).permit(
  :name,
  :date_of_birth,
  address_attributes: %i[ apartment_number ]
)
```